# OSAtomicIncrement64 x class property... what is the advantage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, atomic

If I understood correctly, `OSAtomicIncrement64` should be used to increment a variable atomically. What is the difference/advantage of using one or the other of the scenarios below?

**SCENARIO 1**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  __block volatile int64_t  variable;
}
```

and

```
OSAtomicIncrement64(&variable);
```

inside a block or

**SCENARIO 2**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
  @property(atomic, assign) int64_t variable;
```

and

```
self.variable++;
```

inside the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, adding the `__block` attribute to an instance variable doesn't do anything; the variable is modifiable from the block in any case.

Second, `volatile` doesn't really make a difference here.  That tells the compiler that it can't assume the value is stable, and is used when reordering memory operations at the assembly (machine) level.  It doesn't affect the atomicity of the variable.

Third, the difference between the instance variable and the property is that the property is atomic for both reads and writes.  The update to the instance variable is only atomic for writes (in your example), though it's trivial to make it atomic for reads as well.

This matters in the following scenario:

- 32-bit hardware
- read of 64-bit value

Steps:

1. thread 1 starts load, reads 32 bits
2. thread 2 atomically updates value
3. thread 1 loads other 32 bits

If reads are non-atomic, the above scenario could happen.  If reads are atomic, step 2 will happen before 1 or after 3 (depending on timing), and will in either case read a correct value.

Comment: I have realized the volatile and the __block part just after posting this. Care to clarify your last phrase? *The property will also be atomic for reading, but that's usually not an issue if writes are atomic.*

Comment: Well, I can't think of any examples where non-atomic reads would be a problem if writes are atomic, but I didn't want to write an absolute because there might be some.

Comment: Actually, never mind.  The example is obvious: read half a 64-bit number, have a writer update it atomically, read the other half.  Boom!

Comment: ahhh, I see! THANKS!